# Notifications suddenly stopped working in iOS app

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

My iOS app has been sending notifications successfully since notifications were first introduced in iOS. Suddenly they aren't received on any devices anymore. They still work in development though, just not in production. I haven't changed anything since when they were working last. My certificate is valid.  I'm using the standard PHP code that's posted all over the web to send the notification. It gets all the way through the script without any errors. I recreated the certificate/.pem file and tried everything I can think of but can't figure out why it stopped working. Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Curious. It stopped working across all users with different versions of iOS?

Comment: First check with online APNS notification tester.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NWPusher](https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher) to troubleshoot that issue. With that tool you can test several things like the connection with the apple push notification service, try different payload or see the console logs.

Also make sure that your are testing the production app signed with the production credentials. To check this you should download the app directly from TestFlight or the App Store and test the productions push notifications.